# How to sync all Gnome/Unity settings across multiple machines?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, unity

I have three desktop PCs that I am planning to install either Ubuntu or Ubuntu Gnome on. So I am looking for a way to sync the configurations across them. These three machines are not of the same brand/model. I am wondering if there is a method to safely accomplish this?